# curl returning "failed writing body" only while using scp

Tags: curl, libcurl, scp

I'm trying to implement a few protocols for file transfer using curl.
FTP, SFTP, HTTP work perfectly fine. But in the custom program where I'm using curl, 
the file transfer using SCP fails with

```
Failed writing body (65 != 16384)
```

and sometimes

```
Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

However the same file downloads normally when I use the curl binary itself.

```
curl scp://harsha:password@10.10.10.10/home/harsha/abcd.txt
```

A google search helped me get to [this](http://www.linux.org.za/Lists-Archives/glug-tech-0609/msg00025.html) page where he says that file write function is not writing all the bytes it has read. So I tested it out and indeed found it to be true.

But how do I resolve the problem and make sure all the bytes are properly written.

I'm using **fwrite** by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what code you are using. What are the contents of the 65 bytes which are being returned? (or is that a fail making the initial request?)